# AMD Drivers Is Not Able To Detect My Card

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop Windows 7 , With An AMD Graphics Card HD 8730M , I installed it once then it didn't work so I deleted every file related to AMD ( From Program files(86) & from Program file ) , When I re-installed the driver It was installed successfully , but I don't find the catalyst control center and the files of The Folder " ATI Technology" there is a one folder "ATI.ACE" , Please friends help me ....

Comment: Deleting files from _Program files_ is almost never the correct way to remove programs. You should only use the _Add and remove programs_ part of the control panel.

Comment: how to restore the files , I cant restore it even if I reinstall the software , I formatted my laptop about 8 times to fix the graphics card , I'm tired from that As well that my budget is not good ti buy another laptop

Comment: What happens if you run [AMD's Driver Verification Tool](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/mobile/catalyst_mobility_64-bit_util.exe)?

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same problem. I have HP G62 with 1GB DDR3 graphics card.

1. First try to download the appropriate driver from DELL's website. I repeat from DELL's website i.e, DELL's support website.
2. Then try to install the application using "RUN as ADMINISTRATOR".
3. If it still doesn't work.Go to device manager and Scan for available devices and update device driver..
4. If it still doesn't work then download driver updating software such as driver plus etc. Even then it doesn't works post here.